# mvc grid ajax , grid is updated but the partialview is not

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, grid

While doing maintenance on a C# web application, I encountered [MVC Grid](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Grid.Mvc/). 
One of my views has 4 panels, each panel holds a grid containing a serious amount of data. For performance reasons, I wanted to be able to update each panel separately using AJAX.

In my first attempt, I (re)loaded the panel manually using AJAX. I noticed the grid lost its javascript functionality.

So in my second attempt I installed [Grid.Mvc.Ajax](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Grid.Mvc.Ajax/). 
Now the grid is updated and its functionality is still intact, but I experience the following problem, which I cannot resolve easily:

The grid is updated, but its surrounding panel is not being updated, while you actually have to specifiy the (partial)view containing the grid to be updated. The AjaxGrid.cs contains this method:

```
    public string ToJson(string gridPartialViewName, Controller controller)
    {
        var htmlHelper = new KlaHtmlHelpers();
        return htmlHelper.RenderPartialViewToString(gridPartialViewName, this, controller);
    }
```

To visually prove the partial is not being updated I added a datetime output above to the grid. The grid is refreshed the datetime is not.

```
@using GridMvc.Html
@model Grid.Mvc.Ajax.GridExtensions.AjaxGrid<ReportInReviewViewModel>
<p>@string.Format("{0}",DateTime.Now)</p>
@Html.Grid(Model).Named("reportNumbersGridInReview").Columns(columns =>
                        {
                            columns.Add(reportsinreview => reportsinreview.ReportNumber)
                            .Titled("Report number")
                            .Filterable(true)
                            .Sortable(true);
                    }).SetRowCssClasses(reportsinreview => "row_" + reportsinreview.ReportNumber).SetRowCssClasses(reportsinreview => (reportsinreview.IsAmber ? "amber" : string.Empty) + (reportsinreview.IsRed ? "red" : string.Empty))
```

If only I could enrich the grid with some htmlAttributes or whatever, then I could update the entire panel using that data. It is just some very limited amount of aggregate data shown above the grid.

```
pageGrids.reportNumbersGridInReview.onGridLoaded(function (e) {
    updatePanelData();
});
```

**Has anyone ever dealt with this problem before? And how did you resolve it?
What is the best practice to resolve this problem?**

At this point I am desperate. I am considering removing the grid.mvc.ajax package as a whole and going back to my first attempt. And then just setup the Grid manually each time the panel is reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an accepted answer, but a workaround:

In the controller method you set Session:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [AjaxOnly]
    public ActionResult GetReportsInReviewGrid(int? page)
    {
        //Putting the totals model in Session is a hack, because grid.mvc.ajax will only upload the grid, not the panel.
        var items = GetReportInReviewViewModels();
        Session[STATUSPANELTOTALSINREVIEW] = GetStatusPanelTotalsViewModel(items); //(items); 

        return GetReportsGrid(items, GRIDREPORTSINREVIEW_PARTIAL_PATH);
    }
```

Then onGridLoaded you retrieve that data from Session:

```
pageGrids.reportNumbersGridInReview.onGridLoaded(function (e) {
    UpdateStatusPanelTotalsInReview();
});
```

The corresponding controller method:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [AjaxOnly]
    public PartialViewResult GetStatusPanelTotalsInReview()
    {
        var model = Session[STATUSPANELTOTALSINREVIEW];
        return PartialView("Partials/_StatusPanelTotals", model);
    }
```

This is a working workaround. But of course, this is ridiculous and ugly. The grid.mvc.ajax should just update the entire partialview not just the grid.

As discussed earlier: I might as well just remove the grid.mvc.ajax package and re-wire the grid functionality on each panel update. Both solutions are weak.

Comment: Actually I should mention: [using session](https://www.simple-talk.com/cloud/platform-as-a-service/managing-session-state-in-windows-azure-what-are-the-options/) is a bad idea especially when considering to host the application in the cloud for instance azure.